# Apache thread MEMORY Usage

Tags: apache, memory-leaks

I am facing an issue over the site i am working on, even in very low load of around 10-20 page views per second, the CPU usage maxes out, with all cores running at 100% plus the apache thread memory size keeps on increasing.

We have a server having 4 cores and 34GB as RAM, after some time the memory max out and when i look at apache thread using top command, i can see most of the apache threads in sleep mode but each occupying around 500-600 MB memory.

Its like apache thread is not releasing memory even going into sleep.

Comment: what kind of application is it? Is it Tomcat you are talking about or someother apache project?

Comment: Can you specify which apache server are you asking about? Also I think its problem with the application that runs on the server not the server itself.

Comment: Although this could be application code dependent, with the information supplied this might be better on http://serverfault.com.

Comment: its an e-commerce application having Apache as Web server, apache version running over server is 2.2.22